# Is Graph API 2.x necessary to upgrade facebook php sdk from version 3.2.3 to 4.0.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

With Facebook Upgrading to Graph API 2.x and the New Facebook Login.

Is it necessary to upgrade Facebook php SDK 3.2.3 to 4.0.0?

If it is not, how can I make change for Graph API 2.x base on PHP SDK 3.2.3?

Thank you,

Griffin

Answer (score 0):

It isn't strictly necessary, but v3.2.3 has no support for specifying the graph API version you want to use.

If you are updating an app and want to use graph v2.0+ before Facebook forces it on April 30th, you'll need to use the v4 SDK or hack v3.2.3.  I recommend you just bite the bullet now and use v4. v3.2.3 is deprecated anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Please use latest facebook sdk,
because it old version will be closed.
See change log https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
sdk v3.2.3 (graph api v1.0) available until 2015/4/30

About php, you can upgrade the php verion to php 5.4
or try use facebook sdk for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are another option, not very clean but... you can hack the class.

You can change 
`https://graph.facebook.com/` 
to 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/`
in 
`base_facebook.php`

Be aware with deprecated dates
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I found is to modify $DOMAIN_MAP outside of the vendor code and before you use the Facebook API.

```
$version = 'v2.3';
BaseFacebook::$DOMAIN_MAP = [
  'api'         => 'https://api.facebook.com/' .$version . '/',
  'api_video'   => 'https://api-video.facebook.com/' .$version . '/',
  'api_read'    => 'https://api-read.facebook.com/' .$version . '/',
  'graph'       => 'https://graph.facebook.com/' .$version . '/',
  'graph_video' => 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/' .$version . '/',
  'www'         => 'https://www.facebook.com/' .$version . '/',
];
```